# Any examples for jersey mvc feature with html?

Tags: html, jersey, underscore.js, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

In my application I am using backbone.js and underscore template. I am planning to use jersey mvc feature for single page application.How to render the html page from jersey mvc viewable object?

here I am using jersey mvc feature, i am not using any third party libraries and client side i am using backbone-marrionette js and underscore template. Please find below code snippet.

```
public class testSubResource {  
private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo;
@Inject
private TestService service;
public TestSubResource(TestService service, UriInfo uriInfo) {
    super();
    this.service = service;
    this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
}

@GET
@Template
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
public Viewable details(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    log.info("get test details:{}", id);
    JsonObject response = null;
    try{
        response = service.getTestDetails(id);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    return new Viewable("/test", response);
}}
```

Here it return the json response. I need to pass the json response to jsp...

Comment: Unless there is an underscore template renderer library written in Java, you will need to write the rendering engine yourself, which I imagine will not be easy. If there is a library or if you will write it your, you will also need a [TemplateProcessor](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html#mvc.spi) to make it work with Jersey. If you can't find a library, you may want to switch to Mustache, which already is supported

Comment: Could you please share any examples if you have..

Comment: [Here's](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html#d0e15195) the Jersey setup documentation, [Here's](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) the Mustache documentation

Comment: I am using jersey mvc library.. Could you please share any examples if you have..

Comment: The Jersey examples only has [an example for Freemarker](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.22.2/examples/freemarker-webapp), but you can use that example to see how to configure and use the viewable API. Only difference is the template syntax and the configuration peices.

Comment: here i am using jersey mvc feature only. I am not using any third party libraries.

Comment: Are you not using Maven? Jersey has the `jersey-mvc-mustache`.

Comment: I am using gradle. we are using underscore template.

Comment: Did you not read my first comment. Jersey has no support for underscore templates. You will need to write your own template engine, or find one the supports underscore. From what I searched, I could not find one. So I suggested to use Mustache, which Jersey has support for. I do not have an example for you, so please stop asking me for one. I have provided enough resources for you to get started with Mustache, if that is the route you want to go. Otherwise good luck on trying to use underscore. I was not able to find any resources for third party libraries, so you will need to write your own.

Comment: The vanilla Mvc support will not give you any templating support. It only has support for serving basic static content. You need one of the templating support libraries to support templating. Jersey only has support for JSP, Freemarker, and Mustache. If you search the internet, you will also find examples of using Thymeleaf, but no underscore

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response.

Comment: how to pass the json into viewable object?